# How to compare two different predictors

Tags: r, predictive-models, neural-networks, prediction, model-comparison

I have developed a new predictor based on neural networks for a specific problem in bioinformatics. This predictor takes as inputs several features and returns a boolean target value.  Additionally i have runned my dataset through other already published predictors (none of which based on neural networks). From all these results i have generated 9 contingency tables (one per predictor) based on the target value and the predictor response like the one below.

```
                  Target
              |    0     1 |
           ----------------|
Prediction  0 |  123    10 |
            1 |    5   171 |
            ----------------
```

Is there any way to compare these statistical tables in such a manner that i can state that my predictor is better or worse than any of the other predictors supported by a significant p-value?
Note that i have the results table for all cases (Ei) in my dataset for all the predictors (Pj), like:

```
   P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9
E1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
E2  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1
E3  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's important first to define what is important in this particular problem. Are you looking for best overall accuracy, specificity, sensitivity, precision, AUC, etc? I think if you know the measure you want to use then the results of repeated cross validation runs would provide you a sample of measures for each classifier, you could then use a simple ANOVA to determine if the means of the measure for each run were different between your classifier and the control classifiers. I'm guessing since you said this is a specific bioinformatics problem that you probably have a measure of classifier strength in mind, but if not I'd recommend just going with AUC as it's a little more fine grained than accuracy. I would point you towards

http://arion.csd.uwo.ca/faculty/ling/papers/ijcai03.pdf

If you were curious why I say that. Hope that helps.